# How to properly import from a parent folder?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I have a file tree as such:

```
Root Folder
├───Modules
│   └───RPi
│       ├──__init__.py
│       └──RPi.py
└─program.py
```

**RPi.py**

```
def foo():
    print("bar")
```

**__init__.py**

```
import RPi
```

**program.py**

```
mod1 = __import__("Modules.RPi.RPi")
mod1.foo()
```

When `mod1.foo()` is called I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'foo'`

The reason why I'm using `__import__` rather than the import statement is because the "Module" subdirs and names are known only at runtime.

With that in mind, *how do I import `RPi.py` in `program.py` in a way that it's top level (global) functions and variables can be accessed from `program.py`* (`mod1.foo()` example above)?

Comment: 1. You don't include `.py` when importing; 2. The `RPi` module *doesn't* have a `foo` attribute, you would need to `from RPi import foo` for that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe 1. Just a typo. I'll edit it out. 2. The problem with doing that is that the module name is NOT known before runtime. I can't set a dynamic module name if I use from X import Y and therefore the whole thing I'm trying to do falls apart.

Comment: No, I mean you need that in `RPi/__init__.py`. You should get this working with static imports so you know what names are available at the module level *before* trying to make it dynamic.

Comment: Easy to debug with: `print(dir(mod1))`

Comment: I've tried adding "from RPi import *" to the init py file, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: FWIW, when I execute the exact code (and file layout) in your question with Python 2.7, I get a different error: `ImportError: No module named Modules.RPi.RPi`. Similar issue with Python 3.6: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Modules'`. Being unable to reproduce the problems is grounds for closing a question.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution.

I had to change

```
import RPi
```

to

```
from RPi import *
```

in the **init**.py file

and

```
mod1.foo()
```

to

```
getattr(mod1, foo)()
```

in program.py.